# Need to run custom scripts before compiling/building

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am creating an AIR app. In this app there's a need to copy a folder from a fixed known localtion `C:\xyz` to `app:/`. I would like to know how can I do this copying before compilation/build so that they get packaged when I run the 'Export Release Build'.

Thanks guys in advance... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can copy your c:\xyz folder inside the /src folder of the project. That way it will always be placed inside the bin-debug folder when debugging :) and will be included into the release build.

Comment: Hey Adrian :), this is what I am doing presently. I wanted to have the copying of the c:\xyz folder inside the /src folder to be automated during compilation.

Comment: Then use ANT    http://devdaily.com/blog/post/java/samples-ant-copy-task http://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/blog/index.cfm/2007/6/24/Ant-Copying-files-and-directories or google more about ant task for copy files

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at the ant tasks for compiling your application:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf678b2-8000.html

Comment: Is it possible to run some actionscripts or any other scripts for folder to folder copying using ant tasks? If so, could you kindly post an example snippet?